# How to find new products in a Meteor collection?

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor collection which store products information. The collection also has a createdAt date field. I want to know how I can find products added to this collection in last 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using collection `Products`, you can do it in this way:

```
Products = new Meteor.Collection("products");

function getLastWeek(){
   var today = new Date();
   var lastWeek = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);
   return lastWeek ;
}

if(Meteor.isClient){
   // note you are losing reactivity here:
   var products =  Products.find({createdAt:{$gt:getLastWeek()}}).fetch();
}
```

Above example is really not useful in real world, as you probably want to get products in some template helpers and use reactivity feature.

```
Template.EXAMPLE.helpers({
   products:function(){
     return Products.find({createdAt:{$gt:getLastWeek()}});
   }
})
```

and then use in template EXAMPLE.html :

```
<template name="EXAMPLE">
   <ul>
   {{#each products}}
      <li>{{name}}</li>
   {{/each}}
   </ul>
</template>
```